# Syntax for passing two values into a query for hyperledger fabric?

Tags: javascript, sql, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have this hyperledger composer query where two values are passed in `_$option` and `_$trader`.

```
query selectCallPositionForSeller {
  description: "Select call position based on ID"
  statement:
        SELECT org.tradenetwork.Trader
          WHERE (callPosition.option == _$option AND user_id == _$trader )
}
```

Where callPosition is an array of concepts. That I am trying to call like this.

```
const selectByContract = await query('selectCallPositionForSeller', {'option': option}, {'trader': seller});
```

But I believe this syntax is incorrect.  What is the correct syntax for passing two values?

Also is `user_id = _$trader` the correct way to compare objects?

And does hyperledger fabric allow for a variable number of arguments? (which is what I have assumed in my query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd post an answer to this since the other answer isn't 100% correct and this might be helpful for someone.

Here's the query (callposition is a `concept`)

```
query selectSellerByContractAndCall {
  description: "Select call position based on seller ID"
  statement:
        SELECT org.mining3.tradenetwork.Trader
          WHERE ((callPosition CONTAINS (option == _$option)) AND (user_id == _$seller))
}
```

And it is called like this

```
const selectSellerByContractAndCall = await query('selectSellerByContractAndCall', 
    {'option': 'resource:org.mining3.tradenetwork.Option#' + option.optionId, 'seller': seller.user_id });
```

This is the correct way to pass an object (i.e. option) into the query. Which can have logic on it like this.

```
for(cp of selectSellerByContractAndCall[0].callPosition){
    //logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your syntax is incorrect. Try  calling like this:

```
return query('selectCallPositionForSeller', { "option": option, "trader": seller})
```

And, just in case, put the select like this:

```
query selectCallPositionForSeller {
description: "Select call position based on ID"
statement:
    SELECT org.tradenetwork.Trader
      WHERE ((callPosition.option == _$option) AND (user_id == _$trader))
}
```

hope this help!

Comment: thanks! and is the syntax correct with how I have written the query `callPosition.option == _$option` with `callPosition` being an array of `concepts` in my participant and `option` being a relationship to another asset? Having an issue with the query returning nothing and not sure why.